# Hang text only to button css

Tags: html, css

I have a div like this:

```
<div></div>

<p></p>
```

On the upper div I am doing lots of appends via jquery so no matter what. I want to keep that `p` below that `div`. How to achieve that?

Comment: p will be under your div always.

Comment: Both are block level elements and will remain stacked on top of one another unless you float the div. In which case you would have to clear that float.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep the div block element below the p block element, even when using `float: left;` for example (which is why you ask it I suppose?):

```
div {
    float: left;
}

p {
    clear: both;
}
```

See Jsfiddle for example with a float:
http://jsfiddle.net/tw3G5/1/

Here the float would cause the `<p>` block to move next to the `<div>`, but because the `clear: both;` this won't happen.

Do note that `clear` only applies to block elements. That is why I added them explicitly, just to make it more clear.
Try and apply `display: inline;` to the `<p>` block and see what happens when float is applied to the `<div>` block.

## tl;dr

Apply `clear: both;` to block element to keep it below another block element.

For more info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Comment: Setting a `margin-top: 0px` on the p would also work and not require any of the floats/clears.

Comment: I mentioned that the float and displays are for example purposes. You can do without it, the main property is the clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
div 
{ 
   display:inline-block; 
   width:100%; 
}
```

Now this will always keep your

below then  element;

Answer (score 0):

reaper_unique:

You said:

```
div {
    float: left;
    display: block;
}
```

A div is a block by default. Also, when you float an element, it becomes a block. So you can write just float: left;

securedeveloper:

You said:

```
div 
{ 
   display:inline-block; 
   width:100%; 
}
```

It`s not recommended to "downgrade" an element (div to inline-block/inline) and display: inline-block + width: 100% = display: block

I think that a clear:both INSIDE the div would solve any problem:

```
div:after { content: ''; display: block; width: 100%; clear: both; }
```

Comment: I know that a div is a block by default but I understand the possible confusion, I'll remove the exta unneeded styling. Personally, I'm not too fond of the 'width' as it might hinder the styling of the element later down the road. What if you set the background of the element?